# How to select latest inserted row of items in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have a table current_rate that store current rate of different items with date and time. Here each time the current rate are inserted not updated so that it has historical records of rate variation of each items.
**current_rate ** table

| id | item_id | item_slug | rate | valid_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | wallet | 400 | 2021-05-07 12:24:35 |
| 2 | 1 | bag | 1000 | 2021-05-07 11:13:32 |
| 3 | 1 | bag | 1100 | 2021-05-07 11:45:39 |
| 4 | 3 | mug | 200 | 2021-05-07 12:48:39 |
| 5 | 2 | wallet | 390 | 2021-05-07 12:13:39 |

I'm trying to get the last inserted row based on every item regardless of date and time.
I've tried  `$currentStatus = CurrentRate::find()->groupBy(["item"])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);`
and this will generate Rawquery `SELECT * FROM` current_rate`GROUP BY`item`ORDER BY`id `DESC`
and didn't get the result.
The Result which i want like

| id | item_id | item_slug | rate | valid_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | bag | 1100 | 2021-05-07 11:45:39 |
| 4 | 3 | mug | 200 | 2021-05-07 12:48:39 |
| 5 | 2 | wallet | 390 | 2021-05-07 12:13:39 |

How to get the result like the last inserted(id-autoincriment) of every item.
Regards

Comment: How is this related to `jQuery`

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: i've change date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` along with `SUB QUERY` to get the final output.

**Query SQL:**

```
select * from current_rate
where valid_date in
(select MAX(valid_date) from current_rate group by item_id);
```

**Schema SQL:**

```
create table current_rate(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  item_id varchar(255),
  item_slug varchar(255),
  rate int,
  valid_date TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into current_rate (item_id, item_slug, rate, valid_date)
values (1, 'bag', 1000, '2021-05-07 11:13:32');
insert into current_rate (item_id, item_slug, rate, valid_date)
values (1, 'bag', 1100, '2021-05-07 11:45:39');
insert into current_rate (item_id, item_slug, rate, valid_date)
values (2, 'wallet', 400, '2021-05-07 12:24:35');
insert into current_rate (item_id, item_slug, rate, valid_date)
values (2, 'wallet', 390, '2021-05-07 12:13:39');
insert into current_rate (item_id, item_slug, rate, valid_date)
values (3, 'mug', 200, '2021-05-07 12:48:39');
```

Find the [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=xmVfrQz1Cc)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from `current_rate` where `item_id` = <item_id> AND `item_slug` = <item_slug> AND (`valid_date`, `time`) IN (select MAX(`valid_date`), MAX(`time`) from `current_rate` where `item_id` = <item_id> AND `item_slug` = <item_slug>)
```

You'll get single row every time for item id and item slug combination.